# Drill-through report not recognizing parameter

Tags: cognos-10

I have two reports in Cognos: a parent report that takes a date as a parameter and a drill through report that takes a date parameter from the parent report.  All was working fine until I decided to remove the parameter from the parent report.  I created a data item in the parent report's query using this expression:

```
_add_days(_add_days(current_date, ((_day_of_week(current_date, 1) * -1) + 1)), -7)
```

I then went into the parent's drill-through definition and changed the method of the parameter in the child report from "Pass Parameter Value" to "Pass data item value" and used the new data item as the value.  But when I run the parent and drill down to the child, I get a prompt for the date parameter.  I can't for the life of me figure out why this change should cause the child report to not see the value being passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the fact that the new data item is not part of a the output component (e.g. list or diagram) of your report containing the drill-through definition.

In this case, go to the output component containing the drill-through definiton. In the properties section locate the `attributes` collection. Click on it. Activate the check box next to your new data item and re-run the report.

Comment: I just thought of that on my way to work this morning!  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Here's where my hatred of Cognos goes nova hot.  I can't find the attributes collection in the properties for the combination chart.  I know such a thing exists as I've run across it before, but can't locate it now.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up adding the date to the categories axis of the chart, which allows it to go to the target report.